# Galaxy alpha strange touchscreen "feature" in file explorer

Tags: samsung, touchscreen

I realise this may seem weird but please bare with me.

Recently I updated my Galaxy Alpha to 5.0.2 and I noticed something really strange when using the "My Files" application (not sure if it's because of the update though).

If I hover my finger about 1cm from the screen I can actually select some files.
This only happens only for files with names that do not fit on screen and only in portrait mode.

Is this some hidden accessibility feature or what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is calle **Touch Screen Hoverings** or **Air View**.
This is a feature in new Samsung Phones. For more infor you can look at the documentation on the Samsung Website [here](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/howtoguide/N0000003/20742/298895/SM-G850AZDEATT).

Hope my answer helps!